# How to subtract up to a certain value where both arrays are nonzero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D Numpy arrays, let's say:

```
A1 = [[5,3]
      [4,6]]
```

and

```
A2 = [[7,9]
      [5,0]]
```

I want to be able to select an index of A1, let's say, `[1][0]`, which gives me a selected value of 4.

Now, I want to subtract `A1` element-wise from `A2` wherever both corresponding elements are nonzero. However, where the selected value is less than the A1 element I want to subtract that selected value instead of the A1 element.

In this case, that would mean my final result is:

```
A3 = [[3,6]
      [1,0]]
```

This is because 4 is less than 5, so I subtract 4 from `A2[0][0]`. 4 is not greater than 3, so I subtract 3 from `A2[0][1]`. 4 is equal to 4, so I subtract 4 from `A2[1][0]`. The final value in A2 is not nonzero, so I leave it alone.

Sorry, I don't have a code attempt because I simply don't know how to do this.

Comment: please post the code you have tried

Comment: This paragraph "_Now, I want to subtract A1 from A2 wherever they are both nonzero, unless the selected index is lesser than the index of A1 that would normally be subtracted. In that case, I would like to subtract the selected index's value from that corresponding index of A2 instead._" is not understandable. Rephrase it to make it clear.

Comment: @nbro I interpreted it as the positive difference of the 2 numbers.

Comment: @user3483203 It is the positive difference of 9 and 3 (9 - 3 is 6).

Comment: please do, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which lets us select between two arrays depending on a condition. We first build a mask array that is True where both `A1` & `A2` are non-zero, and False otherwise. I'll call your selected value `val`. Your condition of using `val` wherever the `A1` value is greater than `val` can be done by taking the minimum of `A1` and `val`. Here's the procedure, step by step, so we can see what's going on.

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([[5, 3], [4, 6]])
A2 = np.array([[7, 9], [5, 0]])
print(A1, '\n')
print(A2, '\n')

# Selected indices of A1
row, col = 1, 0    
val = A1[row, col]
print(val)

# Find where both A1 & A2 are nonzero
mask = (A1 != 0) & (A2 != 0)
print(mask, '\n')

# Replace values in A1 that are greater than val
A1a = np.minimum(A1, val)
print(A1a, '\n')

# Only do the subtraction where both A1 & A2 are nonzero,
# otherwise copy the A2 value
A3 = np.where(mask, A2 - A1a, A2)
print(A3, '\n')
```

**output**

```
[[5 3]
 [4 6]] 

[[7 9]
 [5 0]] 

4
[[ True  True]
 [ True False]] 

[[4 3]
 [4 4]] 

[[3 6]
 [1 0]]
```

And in one line:

```
A3 = np.where((A1 != 0) & (A2 != 0), A2 - np.minimum(A1, val), A2)
```

A closely related version is:

```
A3 = A2 - np.where((A1 != 0) & (A2 != 0), np.minimum(A1, val), 0)
```

---

Here's yet another version, courtesy of Andras Deak, which is similar to `np.where`, but should be faster when `mask` has a large number of False entries:

```
A3 = A2.copy()
A3[mask] -= np.minimum(A1, val)[mask]
```